# How to use pixels in Jetpack Compose (for padding, fontSize etc)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

## My Goal

I have gotten a simple Photoshop File I want to recreate what I see there Pixel by Pixel. My Target Device will ***NEVER*** change the Display Resolution or anything else.

[image: photoshop]

It should be pretty simple right? The values in **Pixel** are clear

- width = 111
- height = 66
- padding after divider = 15
- padding after "PM" = 15
- padding between "TIME" and "PM" = 8
- pixelSize for "TIME" = 24
- pixelSize for "PM" = 15

My Code:

```
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(PixelToDp(111))
            .height(PixelToDp(66))
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colorResource(R.color.black)),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.statusbar_splitline),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = PixelToDp(pixelSize = 15))
        )

        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            BentleyText(
                text = "12:34",
                pixelSize = 24,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(end = PixelToDp(pixelSize = 8))
            )
            BentleyText(
                text = "PM", pixelSize = 15,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(end = PixelToDp(pixelSize = 15))
                    .width(IntrinsicSize.Min) //this is something im trying?
            )

        }
    }
```

Where I convert Pixel to SP for Text related stuff

```
@Composable
fun BentleyText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = colorResource(id = R.color.white),
    pixelSize: Int = 14

) {
    val pixelSizeInSp = with(LocalDensity.current) { pixelSize.toSp() }
    Text(
    text,
        modifier = modifier,
        fontFamily = Font(R.font.bentleyw1g_smcon_light_mib3).toFontFamily(),
        fontStyle = Font(R.font.bentleyw1g_smcon_light_mib3).style,
        fontWeight = Font(R.font.bentleyw1g_smcon_light_mib3).weight,

        color = color,
        fontSize = pixelSizeInSp
    )
}
```

Where I convert Pixel to DP for everything else

```
@Composable
fun PixelToDp(pixelSize: Int): Dp {
    return with(LocalDensity.current) { pixelSize.toDp() }
}
```

## Problem

I try to use the exact same values as shown here but everything is way off. First the Font Size doesn't match my Photoshop file's fontSize. Second the gap after the padding is also way off. The only thing that seems to be correct is the Width and the Height.

[image: my_result]

The preview shows me this Lines(Guides)

[image]

Can anyone help me understand Jetpack Compose with this trivial task?

Comment: Do you really have to use `IntrinsicSize.Min` for the width? Why not just set an own value and check what works(even though its not the right choice)?

Comment: No I dont have to. This was my attempt to fix the padding issue I saw the Guides and assumed it starts with a predefined spacing or something. With setting an `own value` you mean `width(15.dp)`. This I have tried.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67664786/how-to-remove-space-below-text-baseline-in-jetpack-compose/68794477#68794477

Comment: how did you achieve this?